# how to get the height of an element after inserting content via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, height

I have a Jquery Mobile page into which I'm loading a form via AJAX. I'm setting the page dimensions using a plugin, which calculates dimensions AFTER the Ajax has run and the layout has been updated (at least the below consoles come in afterwards).

I need to get the height of the element that received the content, but no matter what I try, I'm just getting rubbish ( ~ 169px instead of some 1200px)

Here is my code:

```
(inside plugin)
some: function(){

    var self = this,
    o = self.options,
    wrap = $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true").ui-page-active').last(),
    // elements
    panels = wrap.find('.ui-panel.ui-panel-active').filter(':not(.ui-popover)'),
    pages = panels.find('.ui-page'),
    contents = pages.find('.ui-content');

    // maxHeight contents
    for ( var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){         
        ct = contents.eq(i);

        console.log( ct );
        console.log( ct.css("height") )
        console.log( ct.height() );
        console.log( ct.outerHeight() );    
    // max
    if ( ct.css("height") > parseFloat( o._iPadFixHeight ) ){
        o._iPadFixHeight = parseFloat( ct.css("height") ) + parseFloat( ct.css('padding-top')) +  parseFloat( ct.css('padding-bottom')) ;
        };
    }
     ...
```

If I'm not using any AJAX this works correctly. If I'm adding content dynamically via AJAX, the consoles all fire after the AJAX, but still only return false values.

**Question**:
How can I reliably get the content element height after an AJAX update? I tried setting a 10sec timeout after Ajax to wait until everything is there. No difference, after 10sec the content element height is still not correct.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
Although the consoles log AFTER the AJAX load, I think the function is firing before, so it's calcualting based on pre-AJAX dimensions. I'm thinking to re-fire using this:

```
$(window).on('dimensionchange', function(){             
    self.ome();
    })
```

And triggering

$(window).trigger('dimensionchange')

in my AJAX success handler. Not perfect, but I guess this will do.

**EDIT2:**
Got it to work. @HolgerDSchauf was correct. On my first function run, I set the false values and then after AJAX came in, the false value were still set. I'm now fixing it like this:

Ajax Success:

```
...
// cleanup dimensions
$(window).trigger( 'dimensionclear');
...
window.setTimeout(function() {
   target.removeClass('.fade.in');
   // recalculate
   $(window).trigger('dimensionchange');    
   },250);
```

In my plugin:

```
$(window).on('dimensionchange', function(){ 
     self.ome();
     });
$(window).on('dimensionclear', function(){
     self.ome("clear");
     });
```

And in OME function:

```
// cleanup
if ( from == "clear") {
   contents.css({'height':'', 'max-height':''})
   return;
   }
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Can it be that you have images in your loaded content which have no predefined height and your script is giving the height of the html part without images as they are not loaded yet?

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis: nope. The default element is empty (except a header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used an cache element with "wrap, panels, ct" refresh this cached variable or use it instantly

Comment: I should declare inside the loop?

Comment: I think I understand now. I'm setting height to whatever 160px and once I update I need to remove the 160px in order to calculate the new height, correct?

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to keep all my div's updated sizes. Use something like this, but do not forget to call it when document is ready.

```
function framing() {
    /*
        Pre         : ready.js, self
        Post            : design.js->framing
        Author          : Enes Ü.
        Date            : 15:30, 05 May 12
        Summary         : framing the page widthly/heightly
        Bugs/TODOs              : Frame heights are anormal and will be fixed. Prior=5
    */


    $("#right_menu").width($("#main").width()-$("#left_menu").width());
    $("#left_menu").height(getWinHeight());
    $("#top_menu").width($("#main").width()-$("#left_menu").width());
    $("#right_menu").height(getWinHeight()-$("#top_menu").height());
    $("#map_container").height(getWinHeight());
    /* 
     ******* lots of lines like above...
     */

    setTimeout(framing,100);
}
```

Comment: also a nice approach. But too much overriding for my need.